Linearization of second order, non-autonumous differential equation.
I have come up with a differential equation as follows:
$$a \ddot a = [\frac {1}{2} (1 + \frac {a}{b})(1 + \frac {a^2}{b^2})-2] \dot a ^2 - \frac {4 \mu_{l}}{a \rho_l} (1+ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{a^2}{b^2}) \dot a - \frac{1}{\rho_l} [\frac{2b}{b-a} (\frac{\sigma_b}{b} + \frac{\sigma_a}{a})+ \frac{b}{b-a} (p_3 - p_{2a})]$$
$a$ is the time-varient variable, $b$ and $p_{2a}$ are functions of $a$, and can be described as:
$$ b^3 (t)-a^3 (t) = b^3 _0 - a^3 _0 $$
and
$$ \frac{p_{2a}(t)}{p_{2a0}} = (\frac{a_0}{a(t)})^{3 \gamma_V}$$
all other variables are constant, and the initial values (noted with $_0$) are known.
How can I linearize this equation in the vicinity of the equilibrium position?
The author of the original article (available at ResearchGate) gave an answer (eq.10 in the ref), but I cannot understand how this was obtained:
$$a_e \ddot a' = - \frac {4 \mu_{l}}{\rho_l} (1+ \frac{a_e}{b_e} + \frac{a_e^2}{b_e^2}) \dot a' -[\frac{3 \gamma_V b_e p_3}{(b_e - a_e) \rho_l} (\frac{a_0}{a_e})^{3 \gamma_V} + \frac{2}{(b_e-a_e) \rho_l} (\sigma_b + \frac{a_e^2}{b_e^2} \sigma_a)]a'$$
here $a'$ is a small deviation of $a$ from equilibrium-state($_e$).
The original equation was numbered as eq.4 in the reference.
Can anyone help how such linearization is achieved?
